# Send numbers from php to js in separated files

Tags: javascript, php

How to send variables from php to js in separated files. Can I make this without ajax or I need ajax for this. If I need ajax how to make with ajax.

test.php

```
<?php
$a = 5;
$b = 10;
?>
```

test.js

```
var sum =<?php echo $a?> + <?php echo $b?>
document.write(sum);
```

Comment: you can do this with simply posting your php values to the page with js and retrieve as you have done that will work.

Comment: Can you post here example how to make this

Answer (score 0):

You can get javascript to know about some data you want to transfer from PHP to javascript quite easily.

But you have to make the javascript valid i.e. I think you were missing the `;` at the end of your javascript calculation. It gets a bit hard to see the wood for the tree's sometimes, making sure there is a javascript `;` and a PHP `;`

```
<?php
$a = 5;
$b = 10;
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'var aFromPhp = ' . $a . ';';
echo 'var bFromPhp = ' . $b . ';';
echo 'var sum = aFromPhp + bFromPhp;';

// or your line
echo 'var sum = ' . $a + $b . ';';
echo '</script>';
```

NOTE: Doing it this way does tend to mess up the Global scope in javascript with lots of variables and it not really recommended, but it works.

Comment: But this is php and js in one file. I want to have variable in php and run js file

Comment: You can have more than one `<script>...</script>` block in a single HTML page. These variables go into the javascript global scope and therefore can be accessed from any other javascript block. Although its best to add these before a script block that wants to make use of these variables

Comment: Thanks @putvande I think, couldnt actually see a change, but thanks it made me notice a mistake I had made

Comment: The js will be sent to the browser and run there. You cannot run js while in a php file on the server. Well not if you are just using apache and php anyway.

Comment: I cannot sum in js file php variable ?